# CSS whitespace collapses where rtl and ltr text meet

Tags: css, whitespace

In an HTML page, white-space at the junction between `rtl` and `ltr` text collapses even when using `white-space: pre;` in the CSS.

I want to show all the occurrences of a given word in a given corpus in context. The occurrence should appear in the centre, and the preceding and following text should appear to left and right. The enclosing text should overflow to left and right so that, as the window width is altered, more or less of the context is visible, clipped with ellipses, like this:

> ... text that precedes the **occurrence** and text that follows it ...
>   ... and here is one more **occurrence** which is also centered ...

One workaround is to include a space at the beginning of the central "occurrence" span (as in the first example in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79rc15wp/1/)), but I do not consider this elegant. Is there a cleaner way of forcing the final white-space in the preceding text to appear correctly?

---

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre;
}

span {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}

span.centre {
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

span:last-child {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>long piece of text that comes before an </span><span class="centre">occurrence</span><span> of a word in a given corpus, and that I want to show centered...</span></p>
  <p><span>text that precedes a completely different </span> <span class="centre">occurrence</span><span> of the same word elsewhere in the same corpus...</span></p>
  <p><span>It makes sense to consider that the word </span><span class="centre">occurs</span><span> should also be included since it has the same root as ...</span></p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79rc15wp/1/)

Comment: I think using `direction` for the effect you want to achieve here is rather a misuse of that property to begin with …

Comment: Ignoring the spacing problem, what is the purpose of this styling? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would probably rather go for absolute positioning of the two “parts” that need to be to the left and right of the centered “key word”, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/79rc15wp/3/ (How to deal with that on smaller screens is something you’d have to figure out with your original solution as well.)

Comment: @misorude: Thanks for this fiddle which has helped me understand better the nature of `display:inline`. It is the solution that I have adopted. Perhaps you would like to give it as an answer so that I can accept it. However, I don't see how to add ellipsis at the beginning of the text on the left without abusing the `direction` property : )

Comment: I can’t think of a way to make the ellipsis work with my approach, sorry, that requirement wasn’t part of your question at the time I came up with it ;-) I don’t see a way to make those positioned spans “end” at the browser window with this.

Comment: Yes, a glitch somewhere made it impossible for me to upload the whole question at the beginning, so I posted the bare minimum to begin with and edited it later. I can live with no ellipsis. Ah, and a tweak to your CSS, to remove the need for `calc(...)` https://jsfiddle.net/79rc15wp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Without affecting the html, you can put a space into the `:before` pseudo-element with CSS. You could also add it to the `:after`, so spaces will be visible in both sides of the word even if your text doesn't have spaces inside the tags.

https://jsfiddle.net/79rc15wp/2/

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre;
}

span {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}

span.centre {
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

span.centre:before {
    content: " ";
}

span:last-child {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>long piece of text that comes before an </span><span class="centre">occurrence</span><span> of a word in a given corpus, and that I want to show centered...</span></p>
  <p><span>text that precedes a completely different </span> <span class="centre">occurrence</span><span> of the same word elsewhere in the same corpus...</span></p>
  <p><span>It makes sense to consider that the word </span><span class="centre">occurs</span><span> should also be included since it has the same root as ...</span></p>
</div>
```